# Prometheus Python exporter

Tags: python, json, prometheus

I have written an exporter in Python that converts json to metrics from Prometheus. It works with few data, but when I test this with very many datasets whose spacing is miliseconds, it stops working.

JSON (extract):

```
{
"Acquisition": {
"refTriggerName": "NO_REF_TRIGGER",
"refTriggerStamp": 1666592215243657724,
"channelTimeSinceRefTrigger": [0e+00, 2.5e-04, ...]
"channelValues": {
"values": [4.861855e+00, 4.8581786e+00,
...}
```

json_exporter.py:

```
from prometheus_client import start_http_server, Metric, REGISTRY
import json
import requests
import sys
import time


class JsonCollector(object):
  def __init__(self, endpoint):
    self._endpoint = endpoint
  def collect(self):
    # Fetch the JSON
    response = json.loads(requests.get(self._endpoint).content.decode('UTF-8'))
    metric = Metric('fair_acquisition_signal', 'single sinus signal example', 'gauge')
    valuesArray = response['Acquisition']['channelValues']['values']
    refTriggerStamp = response['Acquisition']['refTriggerStamp']
    timestampArray = response['Acquisition']['channelTimeSinceRefTrigger']

    counter = 0
    while(counter < len(valuesArray)) and (counter < len(timestampArray)):
      timestampV = refTriggerStamp/ 1e9 + timestampArray[counter]
      metric.add_sample('fair_acquisition_signal', value=valuesArray[counter], timestamp=timestampV, labels={})
      #print(str(datetime.fromtimestamp(timstampV)) + ' ' + str(valuesArray[counter]))
      counter += 1
    #for sample in metric.samples:
    #  print(sample)
    #print(str(len(metric.samples)))
    yield metric

if __name__ == '__main__':
  # Usage: json_exporter.py port endpoint
  start_http_server(int(sys.argv[1]))
  REGISTRY.register(JsonCollector(sys.argv[2]))

  while True: time.sleep(1)
```

The data should actually result in a sinus, but in Prometheus it looks like this.
visualization in Prometheus:
[prometheus visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzaol.png)

Does anyone know where my error is?